# Flutter FirebaseMessaging notification is removed automatically when the app goes in foreground

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i clicked the app(not the notification) every notification will removed automatically.
It is a big problem, when the user open the app and all the notification is removed

Comment: I used Firebase messaging 5.14 and flutter 1.74.  The problem I tested in ios 9 and ios 12. The problem are the same

Answer (score 2):

I found a undesired auto cleaning notifications scenario when application entering foreground. It is at line 159 in
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/ios/Classes/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.m

```c
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  _resumingFromBackground = NO;
  // Clears push notifications from the notification center, with the
  // side effect of resetting the badge count. We need to clear notifications
  // because otherwise the user could tap notifications in the notification
  // center while the app is in the foreground, and we wouldn't be able to
  // distinguish that case from the case where a message came in and the
  // user dismissed the notification center without tapping anything.
  // TODO(goderbauer): Revisit this behavior once we provide an API for managing
  // the badge number, or if we add support for running Dart in the background.
  // Setting badgeNumber to 0 is a no-op (= notifications will not be cleared)
  // if it is already 0,
  // therefore the next line is setting it to 1 first before clearing it again
  // to remove all
  // notifications.
  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

It seems a workaround for badge-counter. I also opened a issue: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/114

Comment: I face this issue how can I find this file to remove those lines? @JasperShih